# Main website image when mentioned on social media websites

Tags: java, html, css

I have noticed that when my website gets mentioned on social media websites, an image with a description appears, these details are on my website but they are not what I want to show when the website is mentioned any idea on how I can change them? I have added a favicon but that did not solve the issue for me

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="#{request.contextPath}/resources/favicon.ico" />
```

e.g. go to LinkedIn and create a new post, in the post type the URL for the website and you will get an image of the website with a description.

Please note that I am using JSF.

Comment: The images are pulled out from meta tag: https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en.

Comment: @Noah I have added the metadata to my main html and I can see them when I do inspect element but it did not work

Comment: Did you visit [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context)?

Comment: @Noah I have noticed that it is working on facebook, but on linkedin its not, although it meets their requirements mentioned here: https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use meta tags for social media. Example:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="European Travel Destinations">
<meta property="og:description" content="Offering tour packages for individuals or 
groups.">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://euro-travel-example.com/thumbnail.jpg">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://euro-travel-example.com/index.htm">
Twitter has its own <meta> tags that are similar to the Open Graph
```

or

```
<meta name="twitter:title" content="European Travel Destinations ">
<meta name="twitter:description" content=" Offering tour packages for individuals or 
groups.">
<meta name="twitter:image" content=" http://euro-travel-example.com/thumbnail.jpg">
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
```

Answer (score 0):

The details which show are the meta data description of particular page which is being displayed. Just change the description of the page, you will get the details you want.
, change the description text.